# Reached the maximum number of URI tags from MaximumUriTagsReachedMeterFilter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

the `MaximumUriTagsReachedMeterFilter` configured within [`RestTemplateMetricsAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/client/RestTemplateMetricsAutoConfiguration.java) class logs a warning and stops collecting since I'm using uriVariables badly.

The problem is I have to build URIs with both uri variables and query parameters and pass it to `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange`. For instance:

```
String url = "http://foo.example/api/resources/{id}";

// omitting uriVariables and queryParams maps

URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
        .buildAndExpand(uriVariables)
        .toUri();
uri = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUri(uri)
        .queryParams(queryParams)
        .build()
        .toUri();

restTemplate.exchange(
   uri,
   HttpMethod.GET,
   requestEntity,
   new ParameterizedTypeReference<Entity>(){}
);
```

I really don't know how I could pass to `restTemplate.exchange()` a parametrized string URI together with uri variables and query parameters. This will enable the instrumentation code to pick up the metric uri tag just once since it hooks before uri variables expansion.

Moreover, I'm exploiting RestTemplate metrics for a custom HealthIndicator. I really need to solve this issue.

Comment: Currently, I provided a `@Bean` that implements `RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider` and I customized the tags of the RestTemplate metrics. It is a workaround since I really don't need to use that tag for my `HealthIndicator` (I need only status).

Comment: Can you show an example of how you solved this?  Or the workaround?